# Why button inside form block my event listener?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have created a simple js code:

```
var testContainer = document.getElementById("test");
var butt = document.getElementById("test-button");

butt.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    paragraph.innerText = "test";
    testContainer.appendChild(paragraph);
});
```

With HTML code:

```
<form>
  <div id="test"></div>
  <button id="test-button"> test </button>
</form>
```

And here is the **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arturd/nhnon0Lz/)**.

My question is why when `<button>` is inside `<form>` then my event listener is blocked and it cannot add a new element to `<div id="test">`?
I don't understand why it's not valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nhnon0Lz/2/)**.

Since the `button` is inside a `form` it will be considered as a `submit` button, so when you click in the button the form will be submited then the event will not fire, To avoid that you could add `type='button'` to the button like :

```
<button id="test-button" type="button">test</button>
```

Or use `preventDefault()` like :

```
butt.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var paragraph = document.createElement("p");

    paragraph.innerText = "test";
    testContainer.appendChild(paragraph);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

It appears your button is triggering the form to submit, thus refreshing the page. Try adding e.preventDefault() to your click handler to prevent the form from submitting..

```js
var testContainer = document.getElementById("test");
var butt = document.getElementById("test-button");
butt.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
  paragraph.innerText = "test";
  testContainer.appendChild(paragraph);
});
```

```html
<form>
  <div id="test">

  </div>
  <button id="test-button">
test
</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of your button to

```
type="button"
```